# Insert Boolean in a database using textbox

Tags: c#

hi guys am trying to insert a boolean value using a Textbox, now i get an error that says "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean." because i added 0 in Textbox.

Below is a method in my business layer to insert the values

```
public void ADD_CUSTOMER(string Customer_Code, string Customer_Nmae, string Address, string Country, string City, string Phone, string Fax, string Mobile,
        string Email, string Note, byte[] Cust_Imaige, decimal Credit, decimal Debit, decimal Balance, bool Statas, string criterion)
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DAL.open();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[16];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Customer_Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25);
        param[0].Value = Customer_Code;

        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Customer_Nmae", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[1].Value = Customer_Nmae;

        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[2].Value = Address;

        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[3].Value = Country;

        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[4].Value = City;

        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[5].Value = Phone;

        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@Fax", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[6].Value = Fax;

        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[7].Value = Mobile;

        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[8].Value = Email; 

        param[9] = new SqlParameter("@Note", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        param[9].Value = Note;

        param[10] = new SqlParameter("@Cust_Imaige", SqlDbType.Image);
        param[10].Value = Cust_Imaige;

        param[11] = new SqlParameter("@Credit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[11].Value = Credit;

        param[12] = new SqlParameter("@Debit", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[12].Value = Debit;

        param[13] = new SqlParameter("@Balance", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        param[13].Value = Balance;

        param[14] = new SqlParameter("@Statas", SqlDbType.Bit);
        param[14].Value = Statas;

        param[15] = new SqlParameter("@criterion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        param[15].Value = criterion;

        DAL.ExecuteCommand("ADD_CUSTOMER", param);
        DAL.close();

    }
```

Now below is my client Form

```
 private void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            byte[] Cust_Imaige;
            if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
            {
                Cust_Imaige = new byte[0];

                Customer.ADD_CUSTOMER(txt_Customer_Code.Text, txt_Customer_Nmae.Text, txt_Address.Text,
                    txt_Country.Text, txt_City.Text,txt_Phone.Text,txt_Fax.Text,txt_Mobail.Text,
                   txt_Email.Text, txt_Note.Text, Cust_Imaige,Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Credit.Text),
                   Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Debit.Text),Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Balance.Text),Convert.ToBoolean(txt_Statas.Text), "without_Image");
                MessageBox.Show("added","add",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox2.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox2.Image.RawFormat);
                Cust_Imaige = ms.ToArray();
                Customer.ADD_CUSTOMER(txt_Customer_Code.Text, txt_Customer_Nmae.Text, txt_Address.Text,
                    txt_Country.Text, txt_City.Text, txt_Phone.Text, txt_Fax.Text, txt_Mobail.Text,
                   txt_Email.Text, txt_Note.Text, Cust_Imaige, Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Credit.Text),
                   Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Debit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Balance.Text), Convert.ToBoolean(txt_Statas.Text), "with_Image");
                  MessageBox.Show("add","",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }


        catch
        {
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            btn_Add.Enabled = false;
            btn_New.Enabled = true;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Convert.ToBoolean(txt_Statas.Text)` won't work with `1` and `0`

you should use a `Checkbox` and return `Checkbox.Checked`

or if you want to keep the `TextBox` then

replace `Convert.ToBoolean(txt_Statas.Text)` with `txt_Statas.Text == "1" ? true : false`

Answer (score 0):

I guess a checkbox would be a better fit for that because the value of the checkbox is a boolean.

Anyway, if you want to stay with your TextBox do the following.

```
txt_Statas.Text == "1"
```

Your changed code.

```
Customer.ADD_CUSTOMER(txt_Customer_Code.Text, txt_Customer_Nmae.Text, txt_Address.Text,
                    txt_Country.Text, txt_City.Text, txt_Phone.Text, txt_Fax.Text, txt_Mobail.Text,
                   txt_Email.Text, txt_Note.Text, Cust_Imaige, Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Credit.Text),
                   Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Debit.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Balance.Text), txt_Statas.Text == "1", "with_Image");
```

Answer (score 0):

When converting to boolean via

```
Convert.ToBoolean(txt_Statas.Text)
```

the routine expects the argument in `"True"` or `"False"` form, not in `"0"` or `"1"`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx

in your case just put

```
txt_Statas.Text == "1"
```

instead of `Convert.ToBoolean(txt_Statas.Text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common utility class with *Extension Methods*:

```
internal static class ConvertExtension {
    public static bool ToBoolean(this object value) {
        if (value == null or DBNull.Value.Equals(value)) return false;
        if (value is bool) return (bool)value;
        string obj =  value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj) 
            || string.Equals(obj, "0") 
            || string.Equals("false", obj, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

**usage**

modify `Convert.ToBoolean(txt_Statas.Text)` to `txt_Statas.Text.ToBoolean()`